# Store PHP errors in a log file

Tags: php

I would like to store any errors and warings generated by php in a log file but **still** display them in the normal way (echo) as well.

Thanks

Comment: Did you read the PHP documentation on error reporting and logging? http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.log-errors for example?

Comment: @Dragon i already spend a lot of hours on the manual, anyway this is not what i wanted to do anyway ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your own function and describe what to do with errors.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php

Answer (score 1):

[php.ini](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php) contains two relevant variables: you can specify the log file with `error_log`, and choose whether or not to display the errors with `display_errors`

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% clear on the question but feel it is a combination of error handling:

```
http://us2.php.net/manual/en/ref.errorfunc.php
```

And correctly setting the error handling settings in your php.ini file, or at runtime with:

```
http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php
```

Specifically:

```
http://us2.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php
```

If you have something specific in mind, let me know.